# How to run a command in the background with a delay?

Tags: linux, android

Can somebody show me how to make a program to do this action: after 5 minutes

```
echo "80" > /sys/class/leds/blue/brightness
```

I want this program run in the background (like `rngd` service)
I can't do this because I don't know so much about Linux.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
( sleep 300 ; echo "80" > /sys/class/leds/blue/brightness ) &
```

That way your script continues, or you restore control immediately, while a new *background task* of the script starts, with two commands: sleep, and echo.

The common error is trying to give either `sleep` or `echo` or both the `&` which will not work as intended. Launching a series of commands in `()` though spawns them in a separate shell process, which you can then send whole into background with `&`.

---

To that wit, where I found it actively useful. In an embedded device I develop there's the main application that works with a watchdog. If it fails in a way that triggers the watchdog reset soon after startup, repeatedly, it's hard to fix remotely as the period between the OS start and the reset is quite short, not enough to ssh in, and block the app startup. So I need a way to determine the system restarted so fast and introduce a delay if it did, to give myself time to fix it manually.

```
 [ -f /tmp/startdelay ] && sleep 30
 touch /tmp/startdelay
 ( sleep 30 ; rm /tmp/startdelay ) &
 [ -f /tmp/noautostart ] && exit 0
 start_app
```

If I log in and perform `touch /tmp/noautostart` the main app won't start. If the watchdog kicks in, `rm /tmp/startdelay` won't be performed and the next time the system starts, it will give me extra 30s to stop it. Otherwise restart will be quick, without delay.

Comment: Thanks this is great! I had X take over the mouse and keyboard and effectively freezing the computer. `wait 10; killall X` allowed me to test it without having to reboot every time.

Answer (score 19):

use the `at` command

```
echo "echo \"80\" > /sys/class/leds/blue/brightness" | at now + 5 min
```

that will run in the background

Comment: You can use single quotes to avoid the escaping, and forego `echo` altogether by using a heredoc or herestring.

Comment: I tried 'at' and no command was found on Android 8

Answer (score 7):

If you want something to run in 5 minutes, but the rest of your program to continue (or finish), you need to background the sleep as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

runWithDelay () {
    sleep $1;
    shift;
    "${@}";
}

runWithDelay 3 echo world &
echo hello
```

This will print `hello` and then 3 seconds later (after the main program has exited), print `world`.

The important part is the `&` to fork the function execution into the background.

Comment: May I suggest `runWithDelay () { sleep $1; "${@:2}"; }` instead?

Comment: I think it should read `doWhateverWithDelay 3 &` in your second example.

Comment: @manatwork : Cheers.

Comment: @goldilocks, the essential in using `$@` is that you can quote it and will be expanded as list of quoted words. So better make it `"$@"` (or `"${@}"` if you like the braces). See http://pastebin.com/MU7hbB2C

Comment: @manatwork : Point taken ;)  I did try that using args with echo (`-n`), but obviously that was a bit naive.