# What's the difference between && and ; when forking sleep to background?

Tags: shell, background-process, sleep

I have just [asked a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102945/5216) about forking a process to sleep in the backgroud.
The notation I came up with myself looks like this:

```
sleep 10 && echo "hello world" &
```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102961/5216) to a different question uses a different format.

```
( sleep 10 ; echo "hello world" ) &
```

I know that `&&` only allows the second process to start if the first one returns true. Can sleep fail? Is there a situation where I should prefer one over the other?

Comment: Related: [Difference between executing multiple comamnds with && and ;](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100704/difference-between-executing-multiple-comamnds-with-and)

Answer (score 12):

Sleep can fail if it is terminated during execution:

```
$ sleep 2
$ echo "$?"
0
$ sleep 2
^C
$ echo "$?"
130
```

Since sleep is an external executable, it is also conceivable that the fork or exec calls could fail, which would also cause bash to generate an error code >0.

Answer (score 5):

`a; b` always runs the second command after the first, whereas `a && b` runs the second command only if the first is successful, i.e. only if the first command returns the status 0.

`sleep` always returns the status 0, except when it's killed by a signal, in which case the status is 128 + signal number. (The status can also be 126 or 127 if the `sleep` command doesn't exist or the program is unable to start due to a lack of resources, but you're highly unlikely to encounter these cases.)

Thus you should use `;` or `&&` depending on what you want to happen if the sleep is interrupted:

- `sleep 10; echo hello` prints the message after 10 seconds (less if `sleep` is killed by a signal);
- `sleep 10 && echo hello` prints the message after 10 seconds, but prints nothing if `sleep` is killed by a signal.

Answer (score 3):

You should assume that any command can fail for various reasons even if having sleep fail is indeed very unlikely.

```
( sleep 10 ; echo "hello world" ) &
```

means background sleep and execute echo after sleeping process but if sleep fails echo will run anyway  [see complete explanation](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%28%20sleep%2010%20;%20echo%20%22hello%20world%22%20%29%20&)

```
sleep 10 && echo "hello world" &
```

means you need to wait the end of sleep before echoing anything and if echo fails the process stops but the whole command is backgrounded also. [see complete explanation](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sleep%2010%20&&%20echo%20%22hello%20world%22%20&)

**Conclusion**
the first syntax is shell script which means it's considering instructions separately as a list.
The second option uses && means AND so if you use it iof the first command fail the second will not be executed.

This is just different behaviour in handling errors.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the edit, My post was indeed terribly written